# Struggling compiling a simple c program (gcc)

Tags: c, gcc

I have a very old C program and want to compile to Windows. So I try doing this:

```
gcc -DNO_GLIBC=1 sakide.c -o sakide.exe
```

and this returns:

```
\AppData\Local\Temp\ccx7khiy.o:sakide.c:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `ekiGetLibVersion'
\AppData\Local\Temp\ccx7khiy.o:sakide.c:(.text+0x6b6): undefined reference to `ekiGetLibVersion'
\AppData\Local\Temp\ccx7khiy.o:sakide.c:(.text+0x8ff): undefined reference to `ekiEncodeUrl'
\AppData\Local\Temp\ccx7khiy.o:sakide.c:(.text+0x954): undefined reference to `ekiDecodeUrl'
\AppData\Local\Temp\ccx7khiy.o:sakide.c:(.text+0x993): undefined reference to `ekiDecodeUrl'
\AppData\Local\Temp\ccx7khiy.o:sakide.c:(.text+0xa62): undefined reference to `ekiGetKeyInfo'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This `ekiGetLibVersion` is in a .h file:

```
INT EKIAPI ekiGetLibVersion(char *outBuffer, LPINT outBufferSize);
```

and I also have a .dll name of it.

Ive never compiled anything with C though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows you cannot link against directly with the .dll, you have to link the import library, name .lib. For more information, refer:

On dynamic linking:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682592(v=vs.85).aspx

On implicit linking:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx

Comment: I tried: "gcc -DNO_GLIBC=1 -l sakiCrypt.lib sakide.c -o sakide.exe" still no work, but sakiCrypt.lib is there

Comment: In this case, gcc's syntax is: `gcc -Dfoo sakide.c -lsakiCrypt -o sakide.exe`

Comment: What's gcc's output this time?

Comment: mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsakiCrypt

Comment: Ah, that is, it cannot find the library, so add the directory of the .lib to gcc as well: `gcc ... -L<dir of the .lib> -lsakiCrypt`

Comment: this .lib is in the current directory :)

Comment: Need to add it as long as gcc cannot find it, no matter where it is 

Comment: this way: gcc -DNO_GLIBC=1 -DsakiCrypt sakide.c sakiCrypt.lib -o sakide.exe the .exe is did created, so compiling is success. Its another thing that this exe is bad (cant start), though it begins with MZ.........

Answer (score 1):

You are getting linker errors.

You need to link the library (or object file) where those functions are defined.

Comment: I tried: "gcc -DNO_GLIBC=1 -l sakiCrypt.lib sakide.c -o sakide.exe" still no work, but sakiCrypt.lib is there

Answer (score 0):

Undefined reference usually means the compiler has not seen a proper declaration for this variable. Did you include the header file (which defines this variable) in your C program ?

```
#include "header_file.h"
```

Comment: Headers rarely provide definitions, typically only declarations. If the header were missing there should be compiler errors not linker errors. And if it were missing, adding it would not be likely to fix the linker issues. The problem is failure to link the necessary library.